# R: Insert rows into dataframe by date

Tags: r, dataframe, date, insert, conditional-statements

(R)
I have a dataframe with rows for dates with an available score only.
I want to insert rows with the score 0 on days with no score, and rows with the score 20 on days after the date of death (NA means study object is alive at day 90). Day 1 is defined as the first date with an avaiable score, and I am trying to create a dataframe with exactly 90 rows for each id (day 1 to 90). Do anyone know how to address this? Thanks in advance.

```
id  date        death       score
1   01-01-2001  04-02-2001  14
1   02-01-2001  04-02-2001  16
1   31-01-2001  04-02-2001  15
1   01-02-2001  04-02-2001  16
1   02-02-2001  04-02-2001  12
2   01-04-2001  NA          5
2   03-04-2001  NA          6
2   05-05-2001  NA          9
2   06-05-2001  NA          2
2   07-05-2001  NA          10
```

Comment: What does "score 0 on days with no score" mean with reference to the sample data set? Change an NA in the score column to 0? I would also review this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can try - let me know if this is helpful.

First, make sure your dates are `Date` format (if not already):

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
df$death <- as.Date(df$death, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

You can use `tidyverse` and `lubridate` for most functions needed. Also note that `padr` can be useful for padding dates.

In this case, first `group_by` id. You can use `complete` to fill in missing dates. The sequence of dates used will be from the first date to 89 days later (total 90 days). The `fill` will make the `score` zero for these additional dates added.

Another `fill` can be used to include the date of death for each subsequent row added (since it appears to be the structure used already).

Finally, you can `mutate` the `score` - if `death` is not `NA` and the `date` for a row comes after `death`, then make the value 20 (otherwise just retain the current `score`).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  complete(date = seq(date[1], date[1] + days(89), by = "1 day"), fill = list(score = 0)) %>%
  fill(death, .direction = "down") %>%
  mutate(score = ifelse(!is.na(death) & date > death, 20, score)) %>%
  print(n=180)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 180 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
       id date       death      score
    <int> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
  1     1 2001-01-01 2001-02-04    14
  2     1 2001-01-02 2001-02-04    16
  3     1 2001-01-03 2001-02-04     0
  4     1 2001-01-04 2001-02-04     0
  5     1 2001-01-05 2001-02-04     0
  6     1 2001-01-06 2001-02-04     0
  7     1 2001-01-07 2001-02-04     0
  8     1 2001-01-08 2001-02-04     0
  9     1 2001-01-09 2001-02-04     0
 10     1 2001-01-10 2001-02-04     0
 11     1 2001-01-11 2001-02-04     0
 12     1 2001-01-12 2001-02-04     0
 13     1 2001-01-13 2001-02-04     0
 14     1 2001-01-14 2001-02-04     0
 15     1 2001-01-15 2001-02-04     0
 16     1 2001-01-16 2001-02-04     0
 17     1 2001-01-17 2001-02-04     0
 18     1 2001-01-18 2001-02-04     0
 19     1 2001-01-19 2001-02-04     0
 20     1 2001-01-20 2001-02-04     0
 21     1 2001-01-21 2001-02-04     0
 22     1 2001-01-22 2001-02-04     0
 23     1 2001-01-23 2001-02-04     0
 24     1 2001-01-24 2001-02-04     0
 25     1 2001-01-25 2001-02-04     0
 26     1 2001-01-26 2001-02-04     0
 27     1 2001-01-27 2001-02-04     0
 28     1 2001-01-28 2001-02-04     0
 29     1 2001-01-29 2001-02-04     0
 30     1 2001-01-30 2001-02-04     0
 31     1 2001-01-31 2001-02-04    15
 32     1 2001-02-01 2001-02-04    16
 33     1 2001-02-02 2001-02-04    12
 34     1 2001-02-03 2001-02-04     0
 35     1 2001-02-04 2001-02-04     0
 36     1 2001-02-05 2001-02-04    20
 37     1 2001-02-06 2001-02-04    20
 38     1 2001-02-07 2001-02-04    20
 39     1 2001-02-08 2001-02-04    20
 40     1 2001-02-09 2001-02-04    20
 41     1 2001-02-10 2001-02-04    20
 42     1 2001-02-11 2001-02-04    20
 43     1 2001-02-12 2001-02-04    20
 44     1 2001-02-13 2001-02-04    20
 45     1 2001-02-14 2001-02-04    20
 46     1 2001-02-15 2001-02-04    20
 47     1 2001-02-16 2001-02-04    20
 48     1 2001-02-17 2001-02-04    20
 49     1 2001-02-18 2001-02-04    20
 50     1 2001-02-19 2001-02-04    20
 51     1 2001-02-20 2001-02-04    20
 52     1 2001-02-21 2001-02-04    20
 53     1 2001-02-22 2001-02-04    20
 54     1 2001-02-23 2001-02-04    20
 55     1 2001-02-24 2001-02-04    20
 56     1 2001-02-25 2001-02-04    20
 57     1 2001-02-26 2001-02-04    20
 58     1 2001-02-27 2001-02-04    20
 59     1 2001-02-28 2001-02-04    20
 60     1 2001-03-01 2001-02-04    20
 61     1 2001-03-02 2001-02-04    20
 62     1 2001-03-03 2001-02-04    20
 63     1 2001-03-04 2001-02-04    20
 64     1 2001-03-05 2001-02-04    20
 65     1 2001-03-06 2001-02-04    20
 66     1 2001-03-07 2001-02-04    20
 67     1 2001-03-08 2001-02-04    20
 68     1 2001-03-09 2001-02-04    20
 69     1 2001-03-10 2001-02-04    20
 70     1 2001-03-11 2001-02-04    20
 71     1 2001-03-12 2001-02-04    20
 72     1 2001-03-13 2001-02-04    20
 73     1 2001-03-14 2001-02-04    20
 74     1 2001-03-15 2001-02-04    20
 75     1 2001-03-16 2001-02-04    20
 76     1 2001-03-17 2001-02-04    20
 77     1 2001-03-18 2001-02-04    20
 78     1 2001-03-19 2001-02-04    20
 79     1 2001-03-20 2001-02-04    20
 80     1 2001-03-21 2001-02-04    20
 81     1 2001-03-22 2001-02-04    20
 82     1 2001-03-23 2001-02-04    20
 83     1 2001-03-24 2001-02-04    20
 84     1 2001-03-25 2001-02-04    20
 85     1 2001-03-26 2001-02-04    20
 86     1 2001-03-27 2001-02-04    20
 87     1 2001-03-28 2001-02-04    20
 88     1 2001-03-29 2001-02-04    20
 89     1 2001-03-30 2001-02-04    20
 90     1 2001-03-31 2001-02-04    20
 91     2 2001-04-01 NA             5
 92     2 2001-04-02 NA             0
 93     2 2001-04-03 NA             6
 94     2 2001-04-04 NA             0
 95     2 2001-04-05 NA             0
 96     2 2001-04-06 NA             0
 97     2 2001-04-07 NA             0
 98     2 2001-04-08 NA             0
 99     2 2001-04-09 NA             0
100     2 2001-04-10 NA             0
101     2 2001-04-11 NA             0
102     2 2001-04-12 NA             0
103     2 2001-04-13 NA             0
104     2 2001-04-14 NA             0
105     2 2001-04-15 NA             0
106     2 2001-04-16 NA             0
107     2 2001-04-17 NA             0
108     2 2001-04-18 NA             0
109     2 2001-04-19 NA             0
110     2 2001-04-20 NA             0
111     2 2001-04-21 NA             0
112     2 2001-04-22 NA             0
113     2 2001-04-23 NA             0
114     2 2001-04-24 NA             0
115     2 2001-04-25 NA             0
116     2 2001-04-26 NA             0
117     2 2001-04-27 NA             0
118     2 2001-04-28 NA             0
119     2 2001-04-29 NA             0
120     2 2001-04-30 NA             0
121     2 2001-05-01 NA             0
122     2 2001-05-02 NA             0
123     2 2001-05-03 NA             0
124     2 2001-05-04 NA             0
125     2 2001-05-05 NA             9
126     2 2001-05-06 NA             2
127     2 2001-05-07 NA            10
128     2 2001-05-08 NA             0
129     2 2001-05-09 NA             0
130     2 2001-05-10 NA             0
131     2 2001-05-11 NA             0
132     2 2001-05-12 NA             0
133     2 2001-05-13 NA             0
134     2 2001-05-14 NA             0
135     2 2001-05-15 NA             0
136     2 2001-05-16 NA             0
137     2 2001-05-17 NA             0
138     2 2001-05-18 NA             0
139     2 2001-05-19 NA             0
140     2 2001-05-20 NA             0
141     2 2001-05-21 NA             0
142     2 2001-05-22 NA             0
143     2 2001-05-23 NA             0
144     2 2001-05-24 NA             0
145     2 2001-05-25 NA             0
146     2 2001-05-26 NA             0
147     2 2001-05-27 NA             0
148     2 2001-05-28 NA             0
149     2 2001-05-29 NA             0
150     2 2001-05-30 NA             0
151     2 2001-05-31 NA             0
152     2 2001-06-01 NA             0
153     2 2001-06-02 NA             0
154     2 2001-06-03 NA             0
155     2 2001-06-04 NA             0
156     2 2001-06-05 NA             0
157     2 2001-06-06 NA             0
158     2 2001-06-07 NA             0
159     2 2001-06-08 NA             0
160     2 2001-06-09 NA             0
161     2 2001-06-10 NA             0
162     2 2001-06-11 NA             0
163     2 2001-06-12 NA             0
164     2 2001-06-13 NA             0
165     2 2001-06-14 NA             0
166     2 2001-06-15 NA             0
167     2 2001-06-16 NA             0
168     2 2001-06-17 NA             0
169     2 2001-06-18 NA             0
170     2 2001-06-19 NA             0
171     2 2001-06-20 NA             0
172     2 2001-06-21 NA             0
173     2 2001-06-22 NA             0
174     2 2001-06-23 NA             0
175     2 2001-06-24 NA             0
176     2 2001-06-25 NA             0
177     2 2001-06-26 NA             0
178     2 2001-06-27 NA             0
179     2 2001-06-28 NA             0
180     2 2001-06-29 NA             0
```

Comment: This completely solves the problem. Thank you!